# add an initial line-through text-decoration on a label in a asp listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

My goal is to display a list of tasks with checkboxes.  Checking the checkbox for a task will update the display of the task so a line-through text decoration will appear.  Everythign is working great, except I can't figure out how to initially show the list of tasks with a line-through if they are completed, or normal if the task is not completed.  Here's code excerpts:

```
<asp:Listview .../>
...
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="TaskCompleted" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("TaskCompleted")%>'/
     <asp:Checkbox ID="CompletedCheckbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CompletedCheckboxChange" Checked='<%#IIf(Eval("TaskCompleted"), "True", "False")%>' />
     <asp:Label id="TaskLabel" text='<%#Eval("TaskDesc")%>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
...
</asp:ListView>
```

Then the code behind (minus the database stuff which works fine):

```
Protected Sub CompletedCheckboxChange( ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs )

     Dim Completed As CheckBox = TryCast( sender, CheckBox )
     Dim AnnualProgramTasksId as HiddenField = TryCast(Completed.Parent.FindControl("AnnualProgramTasksId"), HiddenField)
     Dim TaskLabel As Label = TryCast(Completed.Parent.FindControl("TaskLabel"), Label)

     If Completed.Checked Then
         'update task displayed, give it a line-through
         TaskLabel.Style("text-decoration") = "line-through"
     Else
         'update task displayed, give it a line-through
         TaskLabel.Style("text-decoration") = "none"
     End If

End Sub
```

So this works great, when I click on a checkbox the lable gets a line-through or none based on the checkbox.  Only problem is when I initially load the page, I can't figure out how to update the style of TaskLabel to show a line-through or not.  I've tried some various routes, but nothing is panning out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have always done something like whay you are trying to.
Try

```
<asp:Label id="TaskLabel" text='<%#Eval("TaskDesc")%>' runat="server"
         OnDataBinding="TaskLabel_DataBinding" />
```

and

```
Protected Sub TaskLabel_DataBinding( ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs )
   Dim Completed As CheckBox = TryCast(DirectCast( sender, Control).Parent.FindControl("CompletedCheckbox"), CheckBox) 
   CompletedCheckboxChange(Completed, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```